# How to execute the cancel event while browsing file dialog is open in jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation like I have a file upload option and a button on my page which is disable when I will click to brows the file the button will get enable but if user clicks on cancel button it should be disable.
I am stuck in cancel event how to write the jQuery/JavaScript code for cancel event to disable the button again.......
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your title and question body appear to ask different questions. Do you want to do something while the dialog is open, or in response to the dialog being closed?

Answer (score 0):

Give an id name to the cancel button and try the following code where required

```
$("#cancel").trigger("click");
```

Comment: thanks but this the id of cancel button which will be the there in page but how to get the id of cancel button which will be available at brows dailog box ??